# MissingMethodException showing up on save action

Tags: exception, grails

I'm working an example from Grails in Action, specifically implementing a Service for the first time and shifting the work from the Controller to the Service.

I have a Post object containing a User and String content.

The service code is

```
class PostService {
  boolean transactional= true

  Post createPost(String user, String content){
    def thisUser = User.findByUserID(user)
      if (user){
        def post = new Post(content:content)
          if (user.save()){
            return post
        } else
            throw new PostException(message: "Invalid post", post:post)
      }

    throw new PostException(message:"Invalid User ID")
    }
```

}

and the controller code is

def addPost = {

```
  try{
    def newPost = postService.createPost(params.id, params.content)
    flash.message= "Added new Post: $newPost.content}"

  } catch (PostException pe){
    flash.message = pe.message
  }
  redirect(action:'timeline', id:params.id)
}
```

The way this code is supposed to work is an input is made in the form, which is passed to `addPost` as a params object.  Said params object is then handed off to the Service, where a new Post is to be made and bound to the User.

However, I'm getting the error at `user.save()`.  The specific error message is

`No signature of method: java.lang.String.save() is applicable for argument 
types: () values: []`

If I erase the service connector and implement the service code in the controller as

```
def user = User.findByUserID(params.id)

  if (user) {
    def post= new Post(params)
    user.addToPosts(post)

    if (user.save()){
      flash.message= "Sucessfully created Post"
} 

else {
      user.discard()
      flash.message = "Invalid or empty post"
    }

  } else {
    flash.message = "Invalid User ID"
  }
  redirect(action: 'timeline', id:params.id)
}
```

the action works.  So why am I getting a `user.save()` error on the service implementation, but not the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` is the String you're passing to the service method. `thisUser` is the actual User object you're getting that you can call `save()` on.